# Wordpress OpenID doesn't work with StackOverflow

Tags: wordpress, authentication, openid, identity, wordpress-login

To login on stackoverflow, being already logged into wordpress, I select wordpress, then inform my wordpress id into the stackoverflow OpenID login system: myOpenID - and it always logged in. But today for the first time a strange message appears:

> You do not own that identity.

I already followed these steps, but the problem persists:

- [You do not own that identity.](https://web.archive.org/web/20141228130734/http://stackoverflow.uservoice.com:80/forums/1722-general/suggestions/162300-login-with-wordpress-com-says-you-do-not-own-that)

I also tried the same steps on OSX and Linux, using Firefox, Google Chrome and Safari... but nothing changed.

Some others also got stuck with the same problem:

- https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83715/cant-login-with-wordpress-openid-anymore-receive-you-do-not-own-that-identity

So, what is wrong with wordpress openID? And how to get it working again? Or I simply should proceed as [recovering a lost account](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20528/how-can-i-recover-a-lost-account)?

All comments and any help is highly welcome.

Comment: Changing "https" to "http" worked for me.

Comment: @ShreevatsaR - For me it didn't, as I tried all the previously described approaches.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To clean the problem that was not allowing to get logged through wordpress openID, the solution was to get into the wordpress and then I deleted all site URL there:

```
Dashboard >  Settings > OpenID > URL [x].
Delete
```

When I tried again to login again, it asked me to give the permission, and it worked.

I also noticed that wordpress openID works a little bit better with StackExchange than with StackOverflow. So, I finally managed to get logged with wordpress openID through my StackExchange profile. From my StackExchange dashboard, in [my logins], I included additional options for login, such as google openID. Currently I only use google openID as it seems more stable and is working nicely.

Comment: @Binod - In such case, contact the stack overflow staff and they will recover your profile access for you.

Comment: Confirmed it did work for me, even if it unfortunately didn't for the OP.

Answer (score 1):

My problems were different:

1. I hadn't a blog registered to my WordPress username.
2. StackOverflow doesn't use https but WordPress requires you to do that.

Comment: Made it from http to https scheme and everything is ok now. Thank you. (....rel="openid.delegate" href="https://....)